# How can i get Icons from this Software?

Tags: icons

I've been trying to get toolbar icons (not the .exe Icon) from a software called "Roblox Studio" and export them has PNGs, but i don't know how to get them.

I tried using Resource Hacker and Resource Editor but couldn't find anything.

I need the Icons to make an Icon Pack for one of the newer version of the software, i appreciate any help!

Here is a example of icons i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xCx7.png

Comment: What happens when you right click on the software, select Properties, and change ICON?  Do you see the icon?

Comment: If 'them' asked you, I'm sure they can provide you with original icon set? If not try a tool like Resource Hacker. Your question is basically a request for software type one which is OT here. *Trying everything* is very non descriptive and if you have tried everything, what more could we add?

Comment: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/all-roblox-studio-icons/1376612

Answer (score 1):

Some Windows exes have them as a resource.  In which case, you need a resource editor of some sort.

I use one called [Resource Editor](https://melander.dk/reseditor/).  You can open either resource (*.res files when they are outside the exe) or you can open executables (*.exe files, as I have in the screen shot).

You can see a tree structure showing the resources inside it - which include, bitmaps, cursors and Icons).  You can save any resource to a file.

[image]

Disclaimer, I am not associated with it.